# Rounding to at least 2 to 4 decimal places

Tags: c#, .net

How can I round a `decimal` to at least 2 decimal places and have it kept as a `decimal`?

I know I can do this, but it has a code smell.

```
var myResult = Decimal.Parse(myDecimal.ToString("0.00##"));
```

These are the expected results.

```
0.028 -> 0.028
0.02999 -> 0.03
```

Comment: Following on from my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872165/rounding-to-at-least-2-to-4-decimal-places/6872192#6872192) - why would you want to reduce the accuracy of your calculation? Or is it really that you want to format a result of a calculation for display purpose?

Comment: Its for prices. We currently do `Math.Round` with 2 places.

Comment: wondering how to treat `0.02689` ->`0.03` or `0.027` or `0.0269` (As per 2 to 4 decimal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a `decimal` doesnt (or, perhaps shouldn't) have a "number of decimal places" until you format it for display.

Comment: I was going to write this myself, but you beat me to it :) Except for displaying purposes, this should not matter at all.

Comment: I'm sticking this into a `DataTable` for display and its column type is decimal. I'm trying to avoid `Math.Round`

Comment: @Daniel - in that case stick the *real* decimal value in the datatable and format it when you display it... There is always the option of providing a format string when displaying data. (eg, when using `Eval` or similar).

Comment: And 1 more point/reason to do it this way; if somebody decides to use the value from your datatable later for some purpose they should have the full-precision otherwise you will introduce rounding errors. eg, Say I decide to calculate the price of a thousand items from your item-cost column.

Comment: I'm trying to keep any logic in the javascript sane without changing the view :/

Comment: @Daniel - what has javascript got to do with this? You didnt even mention asp.net in your question, let alone client side code.... do you have a *real* question you're not asking?

Comment: this is what i'm requesting. i'm not storing the data in a database. I want to just keep it as a decimal for my presentation.

Comment: @DanielA.White let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1946/discussion-between-jamiec-and-daniel-a-white)

Answer (score 12):

You can use

```
Math.Round(myResult, 4);
```

Comment: Be careful when you state "that won't work". Explain why. Otherwise, people coming here will think there's something wrong with this code, and there isn't. On that note, I assume when you say "that won't work", you mean "that won't work for my purposes".

Answer (score 3):

```
decimal.Round(Decimal myDecimal, int digits#);
```

EX:

```
decimal.Round(100.555555, 2); // result = 100.56
```

Or

```
Math.Round(Decimal myDecimal, int digits#);
```

EX:

```
Math.Round(100.555555, 2);  // result = 100.56
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Math.Round(decimal, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) method:

```
Math.Round(myDecimal, 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use [f format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
var myResult = Decimal.Parse(myDecimal.ToString("f"));
```