# Decimal digit truncating C#

Tags: c#

I have a decimal variable with following values

```
a = 99.9999
b = 88.423766
c = 11.896589
```

Here I am trying to convert with 4 decimal points.

And I used

```
a = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(a), 4);
b = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(b), 4);
c = Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(c), 4);
```

However I get values like

```
a = 100
b = 88.4238
c = 11.8966
```

Though the preferred values are with out rounding,

```
a = 99.9999
b = 88.4237
c = 11.8965
```

How can I achieve it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872165/rounding-to-at-least-2-to-4-decimal-places

Comment: @marsh That question wants rounding, this one wants truncation.

Comment: There is no overload for `Convert.ToDecimal` that has two parameters of which the second one is an `int` -- you probably meant `Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Round(...))` Could you correct your question so the code is actually what you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in function to truncate a `decimal` to N decimal places, but it is very straightforward:

```
a = Math.Truncate(a * 10000m) / 10000m;
```

or as a helper function:

```
public decimal Truncate(decimal d, int n)
{
    // calculate 10^n
    decimal t = (decimal)Math.Pow(10.0,n);

    return Math.Truncate(d * t) / t;
}
```

or as an extension method:

```
public decimal Truncate(this decimal d, int n)
{
    // calculate 10^n
    decimal t = (decimal)Math.Pow(10.0,n);

    return Math.Truncate(d * t) / t;
}
```

Note that the difference between `Math.Truncate` and `Math.Floor` is the handling of negative numbers.  `Math.Truncate` literally truncates the decimal digits, while `Math.Floor` returns the highest integer *less than* the input, so `Math.Truncate(-1.2)` will return `-1` while `Math.Floor(-1.2)` will return `-2`.

Answer (score 1):

This will keep 4 decimals and truncate the rest:

```
a = decimal.Truncate(a*10000)/10000;
b = decimal.Truncate(b*10000)/10000;
c = decimal.Truncate(c*10000)/10000;
```

Comment: It won't. Try it with `-88.423766m`, the result is `-88.4238` (not truncated).

Comment: Oops, missed a zero on the calculation. Negative values is an issue though...